# How can deal with Arabic word in file CSV in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a file CSV in Arabic , how can I deal with it in Python?
Is there any library should I added to anaconda ?
Also how I can write the code to read this file?

Comment: You can use **googletrans** package. Use [this](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/), it will help you install and get started. Let me know if there is a better way out!

Comment: How can I use it with  file of type CSV ? Because I want this file for doing some of data mining techniques ?

Comment: Thanks for all,
the question has been solved.

Comment: If you have solved it with any other procedure apart from the ones we mentioned, please let us know as well. Thanks.

Comment: There are no problems with the Arabic language in Anaconda , Arabic works well with just Excel files.